# What's the phrase for reading a website "cover to cover"

Tags: expressions, synonyms

How do I describe having read a website completely, 'cover to cover'?

Comment: From cover to cover: 
down to the last detail,  from A to Z, from beginning to end, in depth.

Comment: You've read *every page*.

Comment: You've read it from front to back, through and through, thoroughly.

Comment: You've read it completely.

Comment: @Oldcat nailed it. Reading from the beginning to the end is reading completely, which is what cover to cover is.

Answer (score -2):

I have read the website in and out.

Comment: The actual expression is: **inside and out**

Comment: In common usage I have seen "in and out" being used often.

Comment: but not with the verb "read", I'd reckon. And I didn't downvote your suggestion, two other users did.